# jenkins windows environment variables not working

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. I have it installed on a Windows server, running as a service. I have builds running fine, however, I am not able at all to get the environment variables to work. I have tried $BRANCH_NAME, ${BRANCH_NAME}, %BRANCH_NAME% and none of them work. I have setup a parameterized build where I set up a variable BRCHNAME with the default value of one of my branch names, but the variable does not get interpreted properly, it comes through as %BRCHNAME% when it executes the command.

This is from the console output:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "origin/%BRCHNAME%^{commit}" # timeout=10
```

Comment: There are plenty of methods to clone a git repo using Jenkins. Please expand how exactly do you make Jenkins to do this.

Comment: My issue is with accessing the environment variables. Everything is working fine as long as I don't use environment variables. Another example is that I am using the Jenkins/Slack notification plug-in and I want to add a custom message to send to slack. I am trying to use the BRANCH_NAME variable to custom message, but no matter how I reference that variable (as I mentioned above), it doesn't work. Slack is displaying exactly what I put in the custom message field: - %HOMEPATH% - %BRANCH_NAME% - %BRANCH-NAME% -  $env:BRANCH_NAME -  ${env:BRANCH_NAME}

Comment: @izzekil To clarify a little more, What I was trying to show in my question above was that I was attempting to use a variable (BRCHNAME) to access a specified branch in my repo, but when Jenkins actually executes the command it hasn't replaced the variable with the value that is stored in the variable. As you see in the last live above the command actually looked for a branch name of %BRCHNAME% instead of "develop" which was the value of the variable. I don't understand why Jira (or Windows??) is not interpreting the variables properly.

Comment: could you please clarify if your you a Pipeline or a FreeStyle job? If the first then please provide the script or its part, if the latter then try `${BRANCH_NAME}` and ensure you have Token Macro plugin installed/

Comment: @izzekil - I am using FreeStyle jobs and the Token Macro plugin is installed. I've done a little more fooling with this and I was able to get ${} syntax to work, however, it worked for BUILD_ID and JOB_NAME. So I think part of my problem is/was that I was referencing a variable that is not being set for some reason (maybe it isn't supposed to in my case). I have my build set to look at "any" branch and build it if it has had a commit since the last build. I assumed that Jenkins would automatically put the branch that it was building into that variable, but no. Thank you for the help.